# How to override spring beans while keeping parameters?

Tags: java, spring, parameters, configuration, overriding

I have two projects, library and application. Library defines a CommonService interface, which I'd like to override in application. I use Spring XML for configuration.
Code for library:

```
public interface CommonService {
  String service();
}

public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService {

  private String message;
  // + getter/setter

  @Override
  public String service() {
    return "Message: " + getMessage();
  }

}
```

Code for application:

```
public class OverriddenServiceImpl extends CommonServiceImpl {

  @Override
  public String service() {
    return "Overridden: " + super.service();
  }
}
```

Configuration for library (lib-config.xml):

```
  <bean id="commonService" class="spring.context.test.library.CommonServiceImpl">  
    <property name="message" value="Hello!" />
  </bean>
```

Configuration for application (app-config.xml):

```
  <import resource="classpath:/lib-config.xml"/>
  <bean id="commonService" 
    class="spring.context.test.application.OverriddenServiceImpl">  
  </bean>
```

Testing:

```
  @Test
  void testLibraryXML() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/lib-config.xml");
    CommonService commonService = context.getBean("commonService", CommonService.class);
    assertEquals("Message: Hello!", commonService.service());
  }

  @Test
  void testApplicationXML() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/app-config.xml");
    CommonService commonService = context.getBean("commonService", CommonService.class);
    // FIXME!! this gives Overridden: Message: null
    assertEquals("Overridden: Message: Hello!", commonService.service());
  }
```

The problem is with testApplicationXML: commonService should return "Overridden: Message: Hello!", but it returns "Overridden: Message: null".

I've put all the code to github (for sake of simplicity library and application are in one project):
https://github.com/mateattila/spring-test-sandbox

I found out that Spring instantiates OverriddenServiceImpl but not inheriting parameters from pervious definitions. I've tried using bean inheritance but in this case I have to use a different bean id and I'd like to avoid it. I've tried to use Annotation based configuration and it works, but it creates a lot of overhead (see OverriddenConfiguration and testApplicationAnnotation).

Any ideas how to handle this requirement with Spring? I'm also interested in how to extend Spring to work like this.

Comment: Please can you add what output you are getting and what output you are expecting ?

Comment: When using a default name you cannot. The bean is totally overwritten/replaced by the other one and no confiugration is going to be merged.

Comment: @AnishB. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll add it to the post more visibly. See testApplicationXML's FIXME comment. Expected result is "Overridden: Message: Hello!", actual result is "Overridden: Message: null"

Comment: @M.Deinum That's unfortunate in my use case. I'm wondering if it's possible to augment Spring's bean definition loading mechanism to work around this issue? Or: what is the recommended way to achieve this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following up on @M.Deinum 's comment I found the very simple solution: use bean name instead of bean id. Name overriding is working perfectly.
I've committed the fix to the [github repository](https://github.com/mateattila/spring-test-sandbox), here it is anyway:

```
lib-config.xml:
    <bean id="commonService" name="service"
          class="spring.context.test.library.CommonServiceImpl">  
        <property name="message" value="Hello!" />
    </bean>

app-config.xml:
    <bean id="commonService2" name="service" 
          class="spring.context.test.application.OverriddenServiceImpl"
          parent="commonService">  
    </bean>
```

Passing test:

```
  @Test
  void testApplicationXML_FIXED() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/app-config.xml");
    CommonService commonService = context.getBean("service", CommonService.class);
    assertEquals("Overridden: Message: Hello!", commonService.service());
  }
```